# JS equivalent for Golang's strconv.Quote

Tags: javascript, regex, yaml

Given a YAML like this:

```yaml
--- 
body: "something else"
path: site:^example\.com?"something"..."something"
title: "How to do this"
```

parsing it using `yaml-ast-parser`, it results in an invalid YAML because to he period in the regex and the quotes. I can extract the value of `path` and double quote it with `strconv.Quote` and that results in a final YAML like this:

```yaml
--- 
body: "something else"
path: "site:^example\\.com?\"something\"...\"something\""
title: "How to do this"
```

However, `strconv.Quote` is a golang method and this is a javascript project. Does anyone know a way I can achieve `strconv.Quote` in a javascript environment.

Comment: Use `[.]` instead of escaping.

Comment: That wouldn't make the regex valid anymore.

Comment: In regex, `\.` = `[.]`. And it is a valid regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something similar to `strconv.Quote`, use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
// Example value you got from the YAML:
const path = String.raw`site:^example\.com?"something"..."something"`;

console.log("before");
console.log(path);
console.log("after");
console.log(JSON.stringify(path));
```